# USING packages in php from oracle

Tags: php, html, oracle

I cant seem to know why im not able to add using
(ALTER_TABLE_SCOTT.ADD_DEL_EMP)
package to the table EMP in oracle 11g. I'm still new to php and oracle.
Html code:

```
`<table >
<form action="http://alfred-pc:7777/webone.php" method="get">
<td><input type="text" name="ename" placeholder = "EX: Alfred , Elie"><br
</td></tr>
```

the rest of the form all of the same style

```
<tr><td>Alter on Employees: </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="alter"
placeholder = "EX: Insert, Delete, Update"><br></td></tr>
<tr></tr><tr><td></td><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>
</form> </table> </div> </body> </td></tr><tr><td>
<?php
```

Connection to oracle

```
include_once "scottserver.php"; 
include_once "config/config.server.php";
$EMPNO = $_GET["WENO"];    $HIREDATE = $_GET["WEHD"];
$SAL = $_GET["WS"];    $COM = $_GET["WC"]; 
$ENAME = $_GET["WEN"];    $JOB = $_GET["WEJ"]; 
$MGR = $_GET["WMGR"];    $DEPTNO = $_GET["WDNO"]; 
$WWHAT = $_GET["WWAT"];
```

Statement:

```
$s = oci_parse($orclConn, " BEGIN ALTER_TABLE_SCOTT.ADD_DEL_EMP 
('".$EMPNO."','".$HIREDATE."','".$SAL."','".$COM."',
'".$ENAME."','".$JOB."','".$MGR."','".$DEPTNO."','".$WWHAT."'); end;");
oci_execute($s);
```

Parse:

```
$stmtLastParsed   = ociparse($orclConn, $s);

if (!$stmtLastParsed)          {
 print ocierror($orclConn);    }
```

Execute:

```
$stmtLastExecuted = ociexecute($stmtLastParsed, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);       
if (!$stmtLastExecuted) {
   print ocierror($stmtLastParsed);
                        }  
?>
</td></tr>`
```

Comment: Apart from a > missing at the very end. What goes wrong? Do you get any error messages? Can you run the procedure using PLSQL in SQLPLUS?

Comment: Im currently using Notepad++ to code. I have my DB on oracle sql developer 11g. i dont seem to know how to run my script in oracle. (html and php tags are ignored giving this error:unknow command) I have been able to retrieve my table and print on the website, but modifying them isnt working.ALTER_TABLE_SCOTT.ADD_DEL_EMP has the correct parameters.